# How to store WHM data on remote MySQL without ssh

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Is it possible to connect WHM to remote MySQL server without ssh? Thing is I am hosting WHM on Amazon EC2 and want to move all MySQL databases to Amazon RDS, but WHM by default supports connection via SSH which is not the case with RDS.

I am not very familiar with cPanel internals and after unsuccessful browsing around I would like to know if anyone here tried configuring cPanel (WHM) to connect to remote MySQL server instead of localhost. And if it is possible at all even in shell level.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the documentation here:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/pub/AllDocumentation/TrainingResources/TrainingSlides08/RemoteMYSQLServer.pdf

It covers how to do a manual remote MySQL server setup. Its a pretty straitforward process.

Comment: tnx. exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Link not working any more.